# Manually Finding Values of Inverse Trigonometric Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve (for $x$) some problems such as $\arctan(0)=x$, $\arcsin(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}})=x$, etc.

What is the best way to go about this? So far, I have been trying to solve the problems intuitively (e.g. I ask myself *what value of sine will give me $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}$?*), maybe drawing a triangle to help. Is there a better way to solve these problems?

Answer (score 4):

You need to know the basic values of the trigonometric functions, thus for example:

$$\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}3\right)=\sin\left(-\frac{2\pi}3\right)=-\frac{\sqrt3}2\implies\arcsin\left(-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\in\left\{\;-\frac{\pi}3\;,\;-\frac{2\pi}3\;\right\}$$

so you must know where your values' range is.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you wish to ask that if a few of sin x/ cos x / tan x etc are known then how to find x, because the inverse trig functions are, well, functions ie are single valued

The way to go about this is to express all known trig functions in terms of sin x and cos x and then solve for sin x and cos x

To find x if sin x and cos x are known, draw a unit circle and the lines y = sin x and x = cos x, this will basically help you determine which quadrant your angle lies in (instead of actual drawing, try doing it in your head)

Once you have the quadrant, you just compare either sin x or cos x to the known standard angles and that (unto an integer multiple of 2 pi) your answer

Answer (score 0):

A combination of unit circle and "famous triangles" is perhaps the best strategy. Have drawing of the three famous triangles, $30,60,90$,  with sides $1,2,\sqrt 3$, and $45,45,90$, with sides $1,1,\sqrt 2$  and $0,90,90$ with sides $0,1,1$. These will give you the reference angle you are looking for. Then for finding $z$ in $\arctan(a)=z,\arccos(a)=z,\arcsin(a)=z$ locate the axis on the unit circle and apply the definition to find the right quadrant for $z$. For sine the axis is the vertical $y$ axis and final angle is in fourth or first quadrant. For cosine the axis the horizontal $x$ axis and the angle is on first or second quadrant. For tangent the axis is $x=1$ line and the answer is on first or fourth quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you know the values of $\arcsin x$/$\arctan x$/$\arccos x$ for some specific values of $x$. That's just fine. Inverse trigonometric functions are transcendental functions and with exceptions of a few well-known values, the result is not nicely expressible with elementary functions (you can use a calculator or any number of "approximations by hand" to get a numerical value for the angle, but that's not the same).

In addition to the classical angles of multiples of $30^\circ$, which have known values of trigonometric functions, you can use the half-angle formulas and addition theorems to get other angles (inverse functions can be computed by recognizing the half-angle and angle addition expressions and reducing the calculation to a simpler expression).

In fact, the angles you can construct by adding and halving of elementary angles ($45^\circ$ and $60^\circ$), are precisely the angles you can construct with a compass and a straightedge (constructible angles). Such constructions also mean that all the angles, for which you can get the trigonometric function without a calculator (or the inverse problem), have a nice geometric representation of how to carry out such a calculation. Construction with similar triangles and circles is thus a good idea if you have a more complicated expression that you think you can get analytically.

Otherwise, there's nothing wrong about knowing a few special values. We do that all the time.